# Autodesk Forge - Invalid Request URI

Tags: autodesk-forge

recently I ran into an error every time I try to access the Autodesk Forge API.  I haven't made any changes to my code but since last week the line of code shown below throws an error.

```
var content = (StreamContent)client.GetAsync(url).Result.Content;
```

The error text is as follows.

> An invalid request URI was provided. The request URI must either be an absolute URI or BaseAddress must be set.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: An invalid request URI was provided. The request URI must either be an absolute URI or BaseAddress must be set.

I did some testing and it looks like the following line of code returns 'null'.

```
var url = wi.Arguments.OutputArguments.First(a => a.Name == "Results").Resource;
```

So the problem seems to be that my work item is not running properly and not returning a valid output.

My code is very similar to the samples provided by Autodesk and as I said my program was working fine up until last week so I am hoping that someone can help me figure out what is causing this issue.

Comment: Hi, firstly, it looks you are using Design Automation API of Forge. with my experience, the issue you hit is because this work item failed, so there is not any result (such as exported DWG, PDF, or other dataset that the work item should produce). Could you take a look at the report of work item if it has indicated a failure?  The report can be downloaded from wi.StatusDetails.Report

Comment: Thanks a lot Xiaodong, I am using the design automation API and checking the report helped me figure out what was going on. The error was occurring when Forge tried to download my template drawing from dropbox and it was getting an HTTP 301 error. It turned out that changing the url from http to https fixed the problem.